# How can I make my VBA offset code more efficient with loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops, offset

I'm a total newbie to VBA and I have written out a vba code that uses a Sumif formula and applies it columns F through N using a series of offsets based on the activecell. I know there's a more efficient way to do this and was hoping to get pointed in the right direction. I'm doing this sumif formula on a few more variables so will be able to leverage the results.

```
Set ws = Sheets(1)

ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "Total Other Non-U.S. Insurers"
    With ActiveCell.Font
    .Bold = True
    .Size = 9
    End With
    ActiveCell.HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
    
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(6))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(7))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With


    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(8))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(9))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(10))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(11))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With


    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(12))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ActiveSheet.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ActiveSheet.Columns(13))
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Font.Size = 9
    With ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlDouble
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, outside of the sub. Even better is to go to `Tools --> Options --> Editor --> Require Variable Declaration`, and it will always be there.

I hardcoded the loop to be `i = 1 to 8` you can find the last column also if that is the last column.

Referring to Sheets by their index usually isn't a good idea, it can change very easily.

I removed your `Selects` and `ActiveCell` references, they are not necessary.

```
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'Declare your variables
    
    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to whatever your sheet name is
    
    With ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Offset(2, 0) 'No need to Select
        .Value = "Total Other Non-U.S. Insurers"
        With .Font
            .Bold = True
            .Size = 9
        End With
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 8
            'You already have ws set no need to use activesheet
            .Offset(0, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(ws.Columns(5), "Other Non-U.S. Insurers", ws.Columns(i + 5))
            .Offset(0, i).NumberFormat = "_ * #,##0_)_ ;_ * (#,##0)_ ;_ * "" - ""??_)_ ;_ @_ "
            .Offset(0, i).Font.Size = 9
            With .Offset(0, i).Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
                .LineStyle = xlDouble
                .Weight = xlThin
            End With
        Next i
    End With
```

Comment: Warcupine thank you - I had a bunch of code above this but have already included the option explicit as on/activated. I'm getting a runtime error '424' Object required where it says With .font. I thought I had to have an object in order to use the font property

Comment: @BDASkipper Did it place the value in the line above that? It executes no problem for me.